# Expand/Collapse all elements of a Semantic UI accordion

Tags: css, accordion, semantic-ui

I don't find any clue to do that from the Semantic UI documentation/API, is there a clean way to do that?

For now, what I see is to play with :

```
$('.ui.accordion > .title').addClass('active')
$('.ui.accordion > .content').css('display', 'block')
```

Comment: It appears that the API is rather limited, and there is no method you can call to actually open/close all tabs at once. You can add/remove the `active` class to its immediate children, but that means you do not get the pretty transition that comes with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, yes the only thing is see now to do that is to cheat with the normal behavior of accordions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can do this like so:

```
$('.ui.accordion .individual').each(function(i){
    $(this).parent().accordion('open',i);
});
```

You just iterate through each individual element to get its index position, then ask the parent (the accordion) to open each one. This way you still get the transition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```js
onOpen(commentID: string){
 jQuery(`.replies${commentID}`).accordion('open', 0); 
}
```

```html
<div class="ui accordion replies{{commentID}}">
  <div class="title"  (click)="onClick(commentID);">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is the answer to this question?